# Upload files using multipart request - Swift 4

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, file-upload, alamofire

I have to upload files on server using multipart request. For network calls i am using Alamofire.

> What i have done so far is below

**Request Service:**
[image]

**Multipart request:-**

```
let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
            "Content-type": "multipart/form-data"
        ]
        let  fileData = Filedata() // getting data from local path

        let URL = try! URLRequest(url: "https://SomeUrl/upload", method: .post, headers: headers)
        Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in

             //multipartFormData.append(fileData, withName: "image", fileName: "image", mimeType: "image/png")
               multipartFormData.append(fileData, withName: "file")

        }, with: URL, encodingCompletion: { (result) in

            switch result {
            case .success(let upload, _, _):

                upload.responseJSON { response in
                    print(response)
                }
            case .failure(let encodingError):
                print(encodingError)
            }

        })
```

**Response:-**

```
{ Status Code: 400, Headers {
    Connection =     (
        close
    );
    "Content-Type" =     (
        "application/json;charset=UTF-8"
    );
    Date =     (
        "Tue, 15 May 2018 10:34:15 GMT"
    );
    "Transfer-Encoding" =     (
        Identity
    );
} }
[Data]: 171 bytes
[Result]: SUCCESS: {
    error = "Bad Request";
    message = "Required request part 'file' is not present";
    path = "/files/safebolt.org/upload";
    status = 400;
    timestamp = "2018-05-15T10:34:15.715+0000";
}
```

> Can anyone please tell me what i am doing wrong with request ?

Comment: you can use alamofire

Comment: The request i have made is with alamofire.

Comment: are you uploading single image or multiple image

Comment: have you tried `multipartFormData.append(fileData, withName: "file", fileName: "file", mimeType: "image/png")`?

Comment: @GreyHands Please post the above line in answer. i will accept it.. It worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with:

```
multipartFormData.append(fileData, withName: "file", fileName: "file", mimeType: "image/png")
```

Answer (score 2):

I have created one function. Hope it works for you.

```
//Alamofire file upload code
func requestWith(URLString: String,
                 imageData: Data?,
                 fileName: String?,
                 pathExtension: String?,
                 parameters: [String : Any],
                 onView: UIView?,
                 vc: UIViewController,
                 completion:@escaping (Any?) -> Void,
                 failure: @escaping (Error?) -> Void) {

    let headers: HTTPHeaders = [
        "Content-type": "multipart/form-data"
    ]

    let URL = BASE_PATH + URLString
    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
        for (key, value) in parameters {
            multipartFormData.append("\(value)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key as String)
        }

        if let data = imageData {
            multipartFormData.append(data, withName: "fileUpload", fileName: "\(fileName!).\(pathExtension!)", mimeType: "\(fileName!)/\(pathExtension!)")
        }

    }, usingThreshold: UInt64.init(), to: URL, method: .post, headers: headers) { (result) in

        switch result {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):
            upload.responseJSON { response in
                if let err = response.error {
                    failure(err)
                    return
                }
                completion(response.result.value)
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            print("Error in upload: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            failure(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Mine is almost same as yours. Still i am getting the error of bad request.

Comment: What is status code, is it working in postman, is web method is right?

Comment: How you are sending data? Somethign wrong in parameter passing

Comment: What is that FileData()? is it Data Type? See my code var data: Data? = nil
        var fileName: String? = nil
        if targetListDeviceFilePath != nil {
            let path = targetListDeviceFilePath?.path
            data = FileManager.default.contents(atPath: path!)
            fileName = targetListDeviceFilePath?.lastPathComponent
        }  I am picking file from file manager

Comment: class func getFileData(path : String) -> Data {
        if (path.isFileExists()) {
            let fileURL = path.documentDirectoryPath()
             let data = try! Data(contentsOf: fileURL)
            return data
        }
        return Data()
    }

Comment: If picking from File Manager then try my code, and see if it works

Answer (score 0):

Try This, is an example it works for me. If you want to convert encode 64 for images add extension. If simply post the data and image this code may help.

//creating parameters for the post request

```
    let parameters: Parameters=[

        "ad_title":classText1.text!,
        "ad_description":classText2.text!,
        "ad_category":CategoryClass.text!,
        "ad_condition":classText3.text!,
        "ad_username":classText6.text!,
        "ad_usermobile":classText7.text!,
        "ad_city":classText8.text!,
        "ad_price":classText4.text!,
        "negotiable":classText5.text!,
        "image1":adImage1.image!,
        "image2":adImage2.image!,
        "image3":adImage3.image!,
        "image4":adImage4.image!


    ]
    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
        for (key, value) in parameters {
            multipartFormData.append("\(value)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key as String)
        }


    }, usingThreshold: UInt64.init(), to: URL, method: .post) { (result) in
        switch result{
        case .success(let upload, _, _):
            upload.responseJSON { response in
                print("Succesfully uploaded  = \(response)")
                if let err = response.error{

                    print(err)
                    return
                }

            }
        case .failure(let error):
            print("Error in upload: \(error.localizedDescription)")

        }
    }
```